# How can I better calibrate the colors between my iMac and MacBook Air?

Tags: colors

I just got a MacBook Air and the differences in color between it and my 2009 iMac are driving me crazy. I know there were certain iMac models from that period with yellow tinting issues, but I did the gray bar tests and that doesn't appear to be the issue. (No hardware issue suspected)

However, my iMac's tones are more yellow prone than the MacBook and I was wondering how to calibrate these two devices better for design work.

Answer (score 1):

There exist USB devices that you attach to your monitor that contain colorimeters and calibrate your display to be Pantone correct, in theory. This is not an endorsement, as I've never used this device, or any such device, but [this](http://xritephoto.com/ph_product_overview.aspx?ID=1207) is one. Using this in the ambient light you are working in on both devices should make the colors look nearly identical.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Preferences and select display and there you can see colors.There you can calibrate the colors.